# ios 7 : UITableViewCell custom edit button selection issue while scrolling?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm using custom cell in UITableView to display records. I have customized the custom cell delete button while editing and making that button for selection and deselection. The Problem here is while scrolling the tableview I am getting duplicate selection and deselection on button. I have shared the image of selection also.

Please let me know where I have to handle the scrolling issue on selection and deselection of UITableViewCell

Thanks in Advance![image]

Comment: please putt your code here for `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the selection and replace the button image or image

```
imgIconNormal = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_mark.png"];
imgIconSelected = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_mark_selected.png"];
```

in CellForRowAtindexPath

```
    BOOL selected = [[tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows] containsObject:indexPath];
    UIImageView *img = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    img.image = selected ? imgIconSelected : imgIconNormal;
```

and On selection

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIImageView *img = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    img.image = imgIconSelected;
}
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIImageView *imgTrackSelection = (UIImageView*)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    imgTrackSelection.image = imgIconNormal;
}
```

modify your code according to your component. I have used UIImageView

Comment: I am adding custom button in UITableViewCell class since I have to replace the button while editing the cell and I could not find get the status isEditing in  cellforrowatIndex method.

Comment: I think you have to paste your code of cellForRowAtIndexPath in your question.

Comment: Yes your logic is correct.It worked. Since am using same model object for populating table I have used one array to store all objects and compared it cellforRowatIndex whether array contains an object which is already populated or not. And set the state accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Use this before adding the custom buttons:

```
for (UIButton *btn in [cell.contentView.superview subviews])
{
    if([btn isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
    {
       [btn removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```